# Error CS9057 in analyzer Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.dll

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-8.0

I have created a new project on** 8.0.0-preview.6.16**
When I build the project, this error appears:

Error   CS9057  The analyzer assembly '**C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100-preview.6.23330.14\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\source-generators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.dll**' references version '**4.7.0.0**' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '**4.6.0.0**'.

I wanted to update a library but I couldn't find it Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\source-generators\ to version 4.7.0.0
But I didn't find it

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>House.We`enter code here`b</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>House.Web</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Application\Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.MSBuild">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" />
    <PackageReference Include="ZymLabs.NSwag.FluentValidation.AspNetCore" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <!-- Auto-generated Open API specification and Angular TypeScript clients -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunPostBuildEvent>OnBuildSuccess</RunPostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And '$(SkipNSwag)' != 'True' ">
    <Exec ConsoleToMSBuild="true" ContinueOnError="true" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" EnvironmentVariables="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" Command="$(NSwagExe_Net70) run config.nswag /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="NSwagExitCode" />
      <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="NSwagOutput" />
    </Exec>

    <Message Text="$(NSwagOutput)" Condition="'$(NSwagExitCode)' == '0'" Importance="low" />
    <Error Text="$(NSwagOutput)" Condition="'$(NSwagExitCode)' != '0'" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: What VS version are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron  VS version 2022

Comment: This sounds like you're using a non-preview version of Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Try using preview version of VS.

Comment: @MartinCostello I am using version of Visual Studio 2022

Comment: @GuruStron please look at file csproj

Comment: @AlaaBarakat Your comment _"I am using version of Visual Studio 2022"_ seems to be missing an important word.   Are you confirming that you *are* using the preview version?

Comment: @Wyck I am not using the preview version,  I user Community version

Comment: @AlaaBarakat Community version has preview - feel free [to use it](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/#download-preview)

Comment: You need to use the preview of the Community 2022 version with .NET 8 previews.